# snakemake: measure CPU user time, not wall time

Tags: python, snakemake

In snakemake,

**How do I document CPU time spent in user space, not overall runtime?**

I understand snakemake measures wall-time, as well as mean_load. How come snakemake doesn't log cpu user time?

I had an idea of calculating cpu user time from mean_load:

cpu_time = (mean_cpu_load / 100) * runtime_s)
But when I ran several hundred benchmarks, snakemake recorded a mean_load of 0.0 for each run – how should I interpret this? Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

Relevant code in snakemake responsible for benchmarks: https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/src/dc98e2cb51d6bf5046297613a7ca567611c43d30/snakemake/benchmark.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: A mean_load of zero is certainly unexpected. I usually see resonable mean loads. However, there might be situations where the measurement is maybe too sparse, or where the load is really low because of high IO waiting times? I can only say that it worked fine the last time I checked. Maybe try something like a 1min job with guaranteed CPU usage of 1 thread and see what mean load is reported.